# Increase ExtJS TabBar scrolling speed within TabPanel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, tabpanel

I have a ExtJS `tabpanel` with lots of tabs. The current scrolling speed to scroll the tabpanel's title bar is very slow. Is there any way to increase the speed?

When I made the following modification directly to  ext-all-debug.js, the speed increased

```
Ext.define('Ext.layout.container.boxOverflow.Scroller', {
    //The number of pixels to scroll by on scroller click
    scrollIncrement: 400 // increased from 20
}
```

Instead of directly editing ext-all-debug.js, I am looking for ways to override that particular config parameter at the time of TabPanel initialization. Any pointers would be helpful :)

Comment: Instead of editing the original code, you can at least override it. https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?301643-Increase-TabBar-scrolling-speed-within-TabPanel&p=1102306

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like MarthyM said, override it:

```
Ext.define('Ext.override.layout.container.boxOverflow.Scroller', {
    override : 'Ext.layout.container.boxOverflow.Scroller',
    //The number of pixels to scroll by on scroller click
    scrollIncrement: 400 // increased from 20
});
```

Comment: The problem is how to attach overridden scroller to the TabPanel. In fact, this scrolling works on TabPanel's Tab Bar (which is defined as private).

Comment: Won't this increase the scroll increment for all components in the application? Is it possible to just increase the speed for a specific component?